# GKE Config Connector StorageBucket resource times out on kubectl apply

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to apply the following [StorageBucket resource](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector/master/resources/storagebucket/storage_v1alpha2_storagebucket.yaml) from Google's sample manifest:

```
apiVersion: storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1alpha2
kind: StorageBucket
metadata:
  labels:
    label-one: "value-one"
  name: dmacthedestroyer-hdjkwhekhjewkjeh-storagebucket-sample
spec:
  lifecycleRule:
    - action:
        type: Delete
      condition:
        age: 7
  versioning:
    enabled: true
  cors:
    - origin: ["http://example.appspot.com"]
      responseHeader: ["Content-Type"]
      method: ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"]
      maxAgeSeconds: 3600
```

The response times out with the following errors:

```
$ kubectl apply -f sample.yaml
Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "sample.yaml": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s
```

**UPDATE:**
For some unknown reason, the error message has changed to this:

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "sample.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "cnrm-deny-unknown-fields-webhook.google.com": Post https://cnrm-validating-webhook-service.cnrm-system.svc:443/deny-unknown-fields?timeout=30s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I've tested this on two different networks, with the same error result.

I installed the Config Connector components as described in [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall), using a dedicated service account with the `roles/owner` permissions, exactly as stated in the above instructions.

I have successfully deployed [IAMServiceAccount](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resources#iamserviceaccount) and [IAMServiceAccountKey](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resources#iamserviceaccountkey) resources with this setup.

How should I proceed to troubleshoot this?

Comment: On which service account config controller is running/configured (default service account or custom service account)? What procedure did you follow for installing config connector either a GCP Identity [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) or a GKE [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)? Also, while creating an identity what type of IAM service account permissions have you given for config controller (such as --roles/owner or --roles/editor)?

Comment: As @Milad said, what is your cluster configuration?

Comment: I updated my question with that info, thanks for the helpful questions. I'm using a custom GCP service account with the owner permission, as outlined in the installation guide

Comment: I just want to check that you're not actually trying to create a `StorageBucket` with the name `storagebucket-sample`, which is taken (and bucket names must be globally unique).

Comment: updated my question -- thank you. Actually, the bucket name doesn't seem to matter -- the timeout occurs regardless.

Comment: I would suggest you to try to create config connector with default service account to make sure that the issue is not with IAM permissions of custom service account like Kubernetes Engine Service Agent role.

Comment: You nailed it, @Milad! Thanks for pointing that out. Better error messaging could have saved time. Is that worth posting as an issue in the samples github repo? (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-config-connector) I see others doing that for bugs/feature requests.

Comment: Well github repo is not the best place to report this but I would suggest you to open a feature request using Public Issue Tracker. The Public Issue Tracker is a place to report platform-wide issues and feature requests. Follow the [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) and choose "Create new Google Kubernetes Engine issue" from Compute Product to create feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was due to an incorrect service account configuration.

In particular, I was assigning the `owner` role to a different project.

After properly configuring my service account, the timeout errors are resolved.